# How to tidy messy php code

Tags: php, comments, indentation

guys I have this enormous index.php file which is **full** of commented out code like:

```
/*

some code

*/
```

Also the indents are just horrible and inconsequent.

Is there anyway I can tidy up this code, i.e. remove the commented code pieces and fix the indents to some degree?

Comment: Can't you simply delete the comments?

Comment: Yes, there is. By hand. Or figure out how to make your editor do it for you. This is off-topic at Stack Overflow though.

Comment: Netbeans, alt + shift + f. Vim = Beautifier.. mm there's probably other ways too. The best way is to not right poor code.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956911/clean-up-php-html-pages

Comment: You are ruining code by deleting comments.

Comment: From the sound of it the file needs other maintenance as well; since you probably need to go through it anyway, you can just fix everything as you go, including unneeded comments and indentation.

Comment: @meagar: processing a text file to remove certain features is definitely an on-topic programming question.

Comment: @webarto: commented code != comments

Comment: The real problem IMO is `enormous index.php file`

Comment: @nico, just reminds me when I open someones 1500 line code with no comments.

Comment: @webarto: How does deleting commented-out code ruin actual code?  If code shouldn't be there, delete it.  Let deprecated code live in the source control history, not in the production code.  Also, in my experience, most comments are lies (or at least lies waiting to happen).

Comment: @David: I think webarto mistook "commented out code" for "comments", I did the same thing at first. Agree with "You are ruining code by deleting comments" but commenting out unused code instead of removing it is another thing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry 'bout that. Me dumb.

Comment: @nico If that were the question, then I'd agree. But that is not the question.

Comment: How big is this index.php? Anwyway, many IDEs (hell, even Notepad++ has a plugin that allows for code beautifying and regexp search/replace) have features for clearing your code. So take yourself some time and start deleting! If the problem turns out to be spaghetti code, well..time for some refactoring, then

Comment: I usually put certain code between /* and */ if I don't need it at the moment or think it'll get handy some day. My php program is done however so I don't need al those commented out code anymore, but I got like 60+ chunks of commented out code... there must be some way to get rid of them...

Answer (score 4):

Usually a good IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, most other IDEs...) has a code formatter feature. 
It just takes a click like CTRL + SHITF +F in Netbeans to indent your code blocks nicely
Just use it to format. As for commented out code, you just have to remove it by hand.

Comment: I tried ctrl shift f in notepad+, didn't work... I'll try Eclipse as well, thanks for the tip.

Comment: in Netbeans it's ALT + SHIFT + F

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, use PHP... I used this test file http://pastebin.com/VJFzUWHM
This will probably fail in some cases, but worth a shot. Here is the result file http://pastebin.com/1rTYtfta

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents('php.txt');

$string = preg_replace('#\/\*(.*?)\*\/#is', '', $string); # remove forward slash-asterisk asterisk-forward slash comments
$string = preg_replace('#(\#|\/\/)([^\n]+)#is', '', $string); # remove hash and 2x forward slash comments

echo $string;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool, posted to my own web site, but not updated for years.  not sure if it'll help, but lots of people still use it.

http://thephppro.com/tools/beautify.php